# Custom/Owner draw control in PyQt?

Tags: python, user-interface, qt, pyqt, ownerdrawn

I am learning PyQt and wonder if one can create custom/owner draw control like one show in the figure below:

> [alt text http://lh5.ggpht.com/_5XDoB4MglkY/SpoT51SXR1I/AAAAAAAAFcU/ZXjzmhRyDVA/s400/SearchBox.png](http://lh5.ggpht.com/_5XDoB4MglkY/SpoT51SXR1I/AAAAAAAAFcU/ZXjzmhRyDVA/s400/SearchBox.png)

The search box has magnifier icon on its right border. Is this kind of thing possible with PyQt? Thanks!

Comment: See this page: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/customwidgets/
Might give you some ideas.

Comment: @presario Thank you. This is what I was looking for. But the styleesheet suggested by Ants fulfill my need as well :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only need to show an icon, an easy way is to use [style-sheets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html):

```
lineedit = QtGui.QLineEdit()    
lineedit.setStyleSheet("""QLineEdit {
     background-image: url(:/images/magnifier.png);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: right;
     background-clip: padding;
     padding-right: 16px;
}""")
```

Answer (score 0):

Antas Aasma - good anser!
m3rLinEz
Maybe its worth packing all buttons and text labels into one widget. In constructor of that widget connect all buttons. Expose only necessary signals and slots.
Just to reduce code you write (and possibly increase reuse of this widget).